# Bifurcated text

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string of ASCII letters (upper and/or lower case), output the raw MathJax required to display that string bifurcating at each character, into superscripts and subscripts. For example, the inputs `cat` and `horse` would result in outputs which MathJax renders as the following, respectively:

[image: image of cat bifurcating]
[image: image of horse bifurcating]

Note that only one input is required to be taken - these two are listed side by side simply to save vertical space.

## Markup meaning

- `_` indicates a subscript.
- `^` indicates a superscript.
- Braces are required around superscripted or subscripted substrings that contain further superscripting or subscripting in order to prevent them all being at the same level.

## Test cases

Test cases are in the format `input : output`. The first test case shows the empty string as input should result in the empty string as output.

```
"" : ""
"a" : "a"
"me" : "m_e^e"
"cat" : "c_{a_t^t}^{a_t^t}"
"frog" : "f_{r_{o_g^g}^{o_g^g}}^{r_{o_g^g}^{o_g^g}}"
"horse" : "h_{o_{r_{s_e^e}^{s_e^e}}^{r_{s_e^e}^{s_e^e}}}^{o_{r_{s_e^e}^{s_e^e}}^{r_{s_e^e}^{s_e^e}}}"
"bifurcate" : "b_{i_{f_{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}^{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}}^{f_{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}^{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}}}^{i_{f_{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}^{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}}^{f_{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}^{u_{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}^{r_{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}^{c_{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}^{a_{t_e^e}^{t_e^e}}}}}}}"
```

You can see how these are rendered by pasting the output into [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/).

## No redundant braces

MathJax will happily render markup that has redundant braces. For example, the following will all look identical when rendered: `a`, `{a}`, `{}{a}`, `{{{{a}}}}`.

However, valid output for this challenge has no redundant braces. Note in particular that single characters in the output are not surrounded by braces.

## Order

The order of subscript and superscript is unimportant. The following are equivalent and will be indistinguishable when rendered (and are all equally valid outputs):

```
c_{a_t^t}^{a_t^t}
c_{a^t_t}^{a_t^t}
c_{a_t^t}^{a^t_t}
c_{a^t_t}^{a^t_t}
c^{a_t^t}_{a_t^t}
c^{a^t_t}_{a_t^t}
c^{a_t^t}_{a^t_t}
c^{a^t_t}_{a^t_t}
```

## Scoring

For each language, the winner is the shortest code in bytes.

<sub>Too many notifications? Type `</sub>` to unsubscript</sub>

Comment: *Too many notifications? Type `</sub>` to unsubscript* huh who said I want to unsubscript or something? It was a test to see if I read the whole post right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer no it was just a very bad joke.

Comment: Can we just output the compiled pdf result instead?  I would like to write a pure Latex answer.

Comment: @WheatWizard that sounds like a different challenge. It wouldn't be valid as an answer here.

Answer (score 10):

## Python, <s>95</s> <s>90</s> <s>86</s> <s>92</s> 82 bytes

*10 bytes saved thanks to @ConnerJohnston*

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0]+(s[1:]and'_{0}^{0}'.format(s[2:]and'{'+f(s[1:])+'}'or s[1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0WhONogVlujONrQKhbIVY@vNqiNA2J1vbT8otzEEqCMEUSmWl07DaJOU1u9Vj2/CKjVMFZT839BUWZeiUaahrq6piYXnJOIyktC4WbkFxWnAkX@AwA)

Comment: Wow, that is some crazy recursion.

Comment: Some string formatting for 81 bytes (not sure how to TIO link in comments yet):   f=lambda s:s and s[0]+'_{0}^{0}'.format(s[2:]and'{'+f(s[1:])+'}'or s[1:]and s[1])

Comment: @ConnerJohnston thanks! you can put tio links with `[text](link)`, but that's really spoiling ;)

Comment: [79 bytes](https://goo.gl/ftFaMa); and I assume you do not want to use the anonymous function trick, would save 2 bytes though.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>72</s> <s>84</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
a_±b__:={"{",a,"_",±b,"^",±b,"}"};±(a_:""):={"",a,""};""<>Most@Rest@±##&@@#&
```

Uses CP-1252 (Windows) encoding. Takes a list of characters as input.

### Explanation

```
a_±b__:=
```

Define the function `±`, with 2 or more arguments. Label the first argument `a`, and second and on `b`.

```
{"{",a,"_",±b,"^",±b,"}"}
```

Create a `List` equivalent to `"{a_±b^±b}"` (`±b` is evaluated again, recursively).

```
±(a_:""):= ...
```

Define the function `±`, with 1 or 0 arguments. Label the first argument`a`, if it exists, and assign `""` to `a` otherwise.

```
{"",a,""}
```

Create a `List` equivalent to `"a"`, padded with empty `String`s.

```
""<>Most@Rest@±##&@@#&
```

A pure function that applies `±` to the input, drops first and last element, and converts `List` to `String`.

Answer (score 7):

### CJam (35 bytes)

```
MqW%{"^{ }_{ }"{AW$,)3e<#<},S/@*+}/
```

This is a full program. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=MqW%25%7B%22%5E%7B%20%7D_%7B%20%7D%22%7BAW%24%2C)3e%3C%23%3C%7D%2CS%2F%40*%2B%7D%2F&input=abcde).

3 bytes work around a bug in the interpreter (see below).

#### Dissection

```
M            e# Start building from the empty string
qW%{         e# For each character in the reversed input
  "^{ }_{ }" e#   Take a template
  {          e#   If the accumulator is of length n, remove all characters whose
    A        e#   codepoints are greater than pow(10,
    W$,)3e<  e#                                   min(n+1, 3))
    #<       e#   When the accumulator is the empty string, that's all of them.
  },         e#   When the accumulator is one character, that's {}
             e#   When the accumulator is any longer, it's none of them.
  S/@*       e#   Substitute the accumulator for the spaces.
  +          e#   Append to the new character.
}/
```

Note that the `min(n+1, 3)` is to work around a bug in the interpreter: there must be some pattern in the powers of 10 that `'}` is smaller than, but [it's not obvious](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='%7DA50%2Cf%23f%3C).

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for the empty string (first test case).

Comment: @trichoplax, that was due to a subtle difference between GolfScript and CJam which occasionally catches me out. Now fixed at the cost of only one byte by making the code far cleverer than it previously was.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Great explanation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor (At least in the online demo) It does not work for words with more than four letters.

Comment: @dessert, that is very weird, and definitely deserves a bug report against the interpreter. I have added a workaround at a cost of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
f=([c,...s])=>s+s?c+`_${p=s[1]?`{${f(s)}}`:s}^`+p:c||''
```

<s>Θ(len(s)) complexity!</s> According to @PeterTaylor, this is actually Θ(2^len(s)), which is still the best possible...

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for the empty string (first test case).

Comment: @trichoplax Should be fixed now.

Comment: Works perfectly now.

Comment: What is n in your O(n)? I presume it's the length of the output, but unless you state that it is interpreted by default to be the length of the input, and since the length of the output is exponential in the length of the input it's impossible to implement in polynomial time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I had figured that since the algorithm only takes len(input) steps, that the complexity is len(input)... if that isn't correct I'll just remove it from the post since I don't know how to calculate it, unless you know what the correct complexity is.

Comment: If each step were O(1)... But no, the complexity is Theta(2^n)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 71 bytes

```hs
f[x,y]=x:'_':y:'^':y:[]
f(x:y@(_:_))=x:"_{"++f y++"}^{"++f y++"}"
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVdaoQwEH73FCEsmKC9QMDSC/QEVkPWJirVVUykkdCz24lmoXRf9qWUUl8yM9988xcGphH6TXbduqrcpkuRWRbzmC0sLv2bF5Eili1PhDNOKXgxdzhJFFqSBH@UX3QcKWQzu0or@rGTOssJxinCmKYRIlh4XQSjl97quSxlQCphPFRxJ7gpDWTeZXCraai9X3E3cTfwuqyBsktQbrEQ1wyT3mo1nuF52hcF3i732G/YluVebih0btU8wRBbsTN3LXfQ67yl2YZyJgSaa7JbDLT7uXs7P5Qb9L/bOxjH3//W34N17P6x@/9z9zEtol60l6wX4zMiL0SnSFL08IjGqb2Yk4ZDyRDcTKKb4f0ks0whTQFERNpRVka@MvBKj4jKzKLzJgkkiim6Xtf1Ew)

If we just had to output valid code the following would work for 44 bytes:

```hs
f[a]=[a]
f(a:b)=a:"_{"++f b++"}^{"++f b++"}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py06MdYWiLnSNBKtkjRtE62U4quVtLXTFJK0tZVq45DYSv9zEzPzbAuKMvNKVNKUkhNLlP4DAA)

Comment: -5 bytes, based on the 44 bytes version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVdaoQwEH6upwhhwQTtBYT0Bj2B1ZC1iUp1FRNpJPTsdqJZKN2XfSml1JfMzDff/IWBaYR@k123riq36VIwm8U8zpYsLv2bF5EiNlso4Jg7nCQKLUmCP8ovOo4Ussyu0op@7KRmOcE4RRjTNHogWHhdBKOX3uq5LGVAKmE8VHEnuCkNZN5lcKtpqL1fcTdxN/C6rIGyS1BusRDXDJPeajWe4XnaFwXeLvfYb9iW5V5uKHRu1TzBEFuxM3ctd9DrvKXZhnImBJprslsMtPu5ezs/lBv0v9s7GMff/9bfg3Xs/rH7/3P3MS2iXrQX1ovxGZEXolMkKXp8QuPUXsxJw6HMENxMopvh/SQZU0hTABGRdpSVka8ZeKVHRGVm0XmTBBLFFF2v6/oJ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @jferard Nice! I'll add that to the post.

Comment: 66 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVLboMwEN1zCstKhC3oBSy5N@gJaLAcagMqBIQd1dTK2ekYnE2zyaaqqmY18968@dgaaRpp3lXXLYvbG@5YKlJmsiwtwSS6cPl84G5fzIdEE8dm9kkBktSnTJOAsgxfME00ctwtysl@7JThBcE4RxjTPEEEy@DLCHoVUC9UqSJTSRuoSngpbGkvZbQxrKehDnEt/CT8IOqyBslmwbnlYl4zTGbt1QRF0JnQFHSb3XK/cWuVe7Wx0bHV5wkesTY7Ct8KD7Oe1zLro7yNifZa7JYD737tNs4P1Qb/784O4PH3v/X3gB67/9j9/7n7mB6SXrYn3svxBZFXYnKkKHp6RuPUnuwOjipmCGcZMc3wsVOca2TC@UREuVFVVr0xiKrAyMqeZRcgiSKKKbpe1@UL "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 63 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVLboMwEN1zCsuKhJHJBVDJDXoCApZDbUCFgLBR3Tg5Ox2Ds2k22VRVVVYz782bj62RpubqXbTtPEtiks/kEl3Vyz4LbXi9HLI8p1QSx1KahTfPpSYJWZgoSsMCTCCRSc0sDO@GVqg0IxjHCOMoDhDB3Pncg0441DFRCM@UXDuqZJYzXehb4a0Py7GvXFwyOzLbs6qoQLJacB45n1f3o1p61U7hdMo1Bd1q19xv3FLlWa1vdGrkNMIjlmYnZhtmYdZpKbM8ymqfqO/FHjnwnteu4/xQbfD/7uwAtr//rb8HtO3@tvv/c/dxlAcdb85px4dXRI5ExUhEaH9Aw9ic9Q5OJU4QppSouv/YiTSVSMFNxYgIM4hSi7cEosIxvNQTbx0kXhThCN2v6/wF "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 59 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVLbsMgEN37FAhFMgj3AijkBj2BayPigm3Vji2DVRqas7tgk02zyaaqqmY18968@aGRaIR@k123LApZ@kHPmFmKEM1Tl36eD3lREKJQ4AnJ00vkMNvvIS8hThSwzC7Sin7spGY5gjADEOIsAQiK4IsIehlQz2UpI1MJE6iKO8FNaS5ltDGspqEOccXdxN3A67L2ks1655aLec0w6bVXExRBp0NTr9vslvuNW6vcq42Njq2aJ7/E2uzIXcudn3Vey6xLORMTzbXYLee9@7XbOD9U2/t/d3YPHm//W2/v0eP2H7f/P28f4iLpRXtivRifAXpBOgMSg6cDGKf2ZHaaEEgBJATpZnjfScYU0P43hQBJO8rKyFfqozIwojKz6AJEUYQhBtffdfkC "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
±K;{╔+;lH?"{ŗ}”}1 ^Ο+
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JUIxSyUzQiU3QiV1MjU1NCslM0JsSCUzRiUyMiU3QiV1MDE1NyU3RCV1MjAxRCU3RDElMjAlNUUldTAzOUYr,inputs=Y2F0)

Explanation:

```
±                      reverse the string
 K                     take off the first letter - will slowly convert to the output
  ;                    get the rest of the string ontop
   {                   iterate over the rest of the characters
    ╔+                   append "_" to it
      ;                  get the output string ontop
       lH?     }         if it's length - 1 [isn't 0]
          "{ŗ}”            push the string "{ŗ}" where ŗ is replaced by the output string
                1 ^Ο     wrap "^" around with the output string
                    +    prepend to it the current character + "_"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 + 1 (-p) = 55 bytes

```perl
s/\{(.)\}/$1/g while s/([a-z])([a-z]+)/$1_{$2}^{$2}/ig
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6ZaQ08zplZfxVA/XaE8IzMnVaFYXyM6UbcqVhNCaWsCJeOrVYxq40CEfmb6//@JScn/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRga/NctAAA)

**How?**

The substitution in the while condition breaks occurrences of multiple letters in the first letter, followed by the rest in braces like this:

```perl
abc -> a_{bc}^{bc}
```

The while loop executes the substitution until no more multi-letter sequences remain.  The substitution inside the loop removes braces from around single letters.

Comment: Nice, I was wondering how long it would take for a regex answer to show up

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>76</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 57 bytes

Use of lambda saving 4 bytes thanks to [Tutleman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64834/tutleman)

```ruby
f=->s{(r=s[1..-1])[0]?s[0]+?_+[r[1]??{+f[r]+?}:r]*2*?^:s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCsIwEEDRfU8xG0EbGozLQs1BhlFik9iNRmZaiqQ5e6ybD@/z8vjWGofuKvnIg6DRujN0wjNZ2aPsXSGjIWuzisj7KD1Te2ntrZdSD2t28AowuhkipydMiSUUHdw4gU@wrYn91gB8llkg4p/UhLevPw)

Ungolfed:

```ruby
def f(s)
  r = s[1..-1]
  if r.size > 0
    if r.size > 1
      x = "{" + f(r) + "}"
    else
      x = r
    end
    return s[0] + "_" + [x, x].join("^")
  else
    return s
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of a function, use an anonymous lambda (e.g. `->s{...}`), which saves 7 bytes. Then, you can save 2 more bytes by replacing `"#{s[0]}_` with `s[0]+"_`. You can save one further byte by doing inline assignment of `'{}'` to a variable the first time you use it.

Comment: @Tutleman It's recursive (`t=f s[1..-1]`), so I don't think an anonymous function will work, and I already rearranged the beginning of the string, but I can use the inline assignment.

Comment: D'oh! Whoops - I can't believe I missed that. Anyway, it's still shorter to use a (named) lambda: `f=->s{...}` saves 4 bytes, even accounting for the extra `[]` you need when making the recursive call.

Comment: @Tutleman Oh yeah, changed it. Now if I can come up something better than that `.tr` mess...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

```python
def b(s):q=s and(s[2:]and'{%s}'or'%s')%b(s[1:]);return s[1:]and s[0]+'^%s_'%q+q or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEAC/spewWXrRHiO@pMQSbcVeNsluShHx7XHxNgPDlHd7ZR57X9Yn3L1SqFeFxIvXaQzRAD9Ov5gFnSI5S6ZziHSRte3C8DerDE5xwJvTGV0dKmQB7UU2braVdMwbl715ov5I7Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 47 bytes

```
Ljk[hb|&ttbs[\_\{ytb"}^{"ytb\})&tbs[\_htb\^htb;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3ycrOzojqUatpCSpODomPqa6siRJqTauWglIx9RqqkGEM4CcOCBh/b/yv1JGflFxqhIA)

This is pretty much a straight port of @Uriel's Python answer.  Going to golf it down in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 121 bytes

```
function b($s){return $s[0].($s[1]?'_'.($s[2]?'{'.($b=b(substr($s,1))).'}^{'.$b.'}':"$s[1]^$s[1]"):'');}echo b($argv[1]);
```

The function itself is 104 bytes and shows a PHP Notice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 43 bytes

```
(.)(.)$
$1¶$2
+`(.)¶(.*)
¶{$1_$2^$2}
¶{|}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0NPE4hUuFQMD21TMeLSTgDyDm3T0NPS5Dq0rVrFMF7FKE7FqBbEqalV4fr/P5ErN5UrObGEK60oP50rI7@oOJUrKTOttAgolgoA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(.)(.)$
$1¶$2
```

Get the ball rolling by slicing off the last character. (But if it's the only character, them leave it alone.)

```
+`(.)¶(.*)
¶{$1_$2^$2}
```

Move the ¶ character back one step at a time, each time taking the previous result and making it a subscript and superscript of the next character.

```
¶{|}$
```

Remove the now redundant ¶ and the outer {}s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 121 bytes

```java
s->{int l=s.length;String r=--l<0?"":""+s[l];for(;l-->0;)r="{"+s[l]+"_"+r+"^"+r+"}";return r.replaceAll("^\\{|\\}$","");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBbsIwDL3zFZa1Q6vSiDOlTGjSbjtxpDCFLi1hIamcFAl1/fYupR10kZL42c/Wez7zK49NJfT567ur6qOSOeSKWwsfXGpoZgBj1jru/Hc18gsuvhZsHUld7vbAqbThnQpw9vNY7aRiRa1zJ41m72Owyk@cdvv50LeGoyxqyrkzBCl0Nl43UjtQqWVK6NKdkoEIlMaxWi1eEZeIkd2pfVIYChIVx@tFElKKzZCO8BMjivBwf1tMSLiaNBAjUSmei41SAR6yrPnJsvYF54hh0nbJXfjDjRPWWa9o8NMfxPkz5lNwEVPkvUxhQaac4pMh@4//twCBY64dpPTuRu@9mOUgKXwo2t6sExdmascqz3JKB89dMl5V6hb0LcyZN7/yDRG/BWEYDtPbWX/b7hc)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 73 Bytes

```js
s=>[...s].reduceRight((m,c)=>`${c}_{${m}}^{${m}}`).replace(/{(.)}/g,'$1')
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>                                  // take the input string
    [...s]                           // split the string into an array
    .reduceRight(                    // reduce the array in reverse order
        (m,c)=>`${c}_{${m}}^{${m}}`  // storing the result of each iteration in the memo m
    )                                // and returning m at the end
    .replace(/{(.)}/g,'$1')          // replace redundant {}
```

Because there is no specified initial value of `m`, `reduceRight` takes the last element of `s` as the initial value, and begins iterating at index `s.length-2`.

```js
const f=s=>[...s].reduceRight((m,c)=>`${c}_{${m}}^{${m}}`).replace(/{(.)}/g,'$1');

const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
output.textContent = f(input.value);
input.addEventListener('keyup', e => output.textContent = f(input.value));
```

```html
Enter text to bifurcate: <input type="text" id="input" value="cat" />
<br />
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: ``s=>[...s].reduceRight((m,c)=>`{${c}_${m}^${m}}`).slice(1,-1)`` is only 60 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for the empty string (first test case).