# Generate TeX to typeset Sierpinski Triangle Fractal

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, code-generation, fractal

## Challenge

Write code that outputs TeX (LaTeX) math-equation code (given below) that will typeset Sierpinski Triangle Fractal of 5 levels. **Shortest code wins**.

## Details

TeX (and friends like LaTeX, etc.) is a sophisticated typesetting system. It can render arbitrary nested complex expressions for mathematical formulas. Coincidentally this "nested complex" is also descriptive of fractals. The following is rendered with MathJaX

$${{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}^{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}_{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}}$$

by the following plain-text math-equation code consisting of nested super- and sub-scripts:

```
{{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}^{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}_{{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}^{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}_{{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}^{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}_{{x^x_x}^{x^x_x}_{x^x_x}}}}}
```

Note this is just a 5-level nesting. You do not need to generate `$...$` or `$$...$$` or other markup required to start/end a math equation in TeX & Co. You can preview generated TeX in many online editors, for instance:  http://www.hostmath.com but you can find many others too. This question was inspired by a [discussion with friends](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1188472).

## Update

There is a [similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/138245/4997) but it much more general and will produce different solutions. I wanted to see really kolmogorov-complexity for a very fixed simple code that in one system (TeX) is completely explicit while in another compressed. This also address the `n` instead of 5 levels comment.

Comment: Why exactly 5 levels? It would be interesting (and probably easier) to implement arbitrary number of levels and to take level number as a parameter.

Comment: @ThePirateBay yes, sure, but i did not want to generalize, see my update.

Comment: Hello; I closed your question as a duplicate because I believe that answers can be too trivially modified from the other question to answer this question. However, I like the idea and I think it looks pretty cool! :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I reopened this question as I do not see the code as being trivially modifiable to translate from one to the other.

Comment: That's *far* too quick to be accepting a solution!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino was the question open again?

Comment: @Shaggy I removed acceptance for now because there is some confusion with opening and closing the question. Sorry.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes, AdmBorkBork hammered it: *For what it's worth, I reopened this question as I do not see the code as being trivially modifiable to translate from one to the other.*.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork thank you for your consideration

Comment: Relevant Meta: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5056/32352

Comment: When I saw this challenge, this answer came to my mind... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6830/67961  and... it was yours

Comment: @Jenny_mathy yeah guilty as charged ;-)

Comment: Is the challenge just to generate that TeX string, or to generate any TeX string which will have the same output?

Comment: @TRiG "any TeX string which will have the same output"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>16</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
 x5{"{^_}”;∑
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIweDUlN0IlMjIlN0IlNUVfJTdEJXUyMDFEJTNCJXUyMjEx)

Port of Erik The Outgolfer's [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143276/59183)

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
exec"print'x'"+".join('{^_}')"*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVmpoCgzr0S9Ql1JW0kvKz8zT0O9Oi6@Vl1TScv0/38A)

Answer (score 15):

## plain TeX, 29 bytes

```
\def~#1x{{#1x_#1x^#1x}}~~~~~x
```

That outputs what others have output. But if we need the code to be compilable it would be 6 bytes more

```
\def~#1x{{#1x_#1x^#1x}}$~~~~~x$\bye
```

**Explanation**

`~` is an [active character](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-activechars.html) in TeX, so we can give it a (new) definition.

`\def~#1x{{#1x_#1x^#1x}}` defines `~` as a macro, so that when TeX sees `~`, it does the following:

- Read everything up to the next `x`, and call that `#1` (pattern-matching).
- Replace the whole thing with `{#1x_#1x^#1x}`

For example, `~ABCx` would get replaced with `{ABCx_ABCx^ABCx}`.

When `~~~~~x` is used, `#1` is `~~~~`, so the whole thing gets replaced with `{~~~~x_~~~~x^~~~~x}`. And so on.

Once we have the long string, we can print it out to terminal with `\message` (and ending with a `\bye` so TeX stops), so `\message{~~~~~x}\bye`. Or typeset the resulting expression (as a mathematical formula), by surrounding it in `$`s : so `$~~~~~x$\bye`.

Comment: Sorry if there's anything wrong, first answer here.

Comment: For a big `n` (rather than `5`) it could be more efficient to create a macro that outputs a list of `n` tildes `~` rather than writing `~~~~~`. Plus it would look better if the whole expression is typeset under `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: Nice trick… can you add an explanation, or mind if I add one? This illustrates a nice feature of pattern-matching in TeX macros, which is not a feature common to many languages (that I know of).

Comment: I will add it, but feel free to edit.

Comment: Oops, didn't see your comment… added a very similar explanation; feel free to reject. +1 for the nice answer!

Comment: Almost word for word :)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell),  <s>44</s>  35 bytes

```powershell
"'x'"+"-replace'x','{x^x_x}'"*5|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0m9Ql1JW0m3KLUgJzE5FcjTUa@uiKuIr6hVV9IyrclMrfj//79GdHJGYlF0bKx6UUZlSUZusbomAA)

Uses string multiplication to repeatedly `-replace` `x`es with the sub- and super-scripts, then output.

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to Joey.*

Comment: `"'x'"+"-replace'x','{x^x_x}'"*5|iex` is a bit easier, no?

Comment: @Joey Oh, that's a clever way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
'x5F'x¡"{x^x_x}"ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fvcLUTb3i0EKl6oq4iviKWqXDe///BwA)

**Explanation**

```
'x                  # push "x"
  5F                # 5 times do
    'x¡             # split on "x"
       "{x^x_x}"ý   # join on "{x^x_x}"
```

**Other programs at the same byte-count include**

```
"{x^x_x}"©4F'x¡®ý
'x5F'x"{x^x_x}".:
```

Comment: I feel like `"{x^x_x}"` can be reduced ._.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
f=n=>n>4?'x':[...'{^_}'].join(f(-~n))
```

Edit: Saved <s>3</s> 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Specifying 5 still costs me 2 bytes; this <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 35-byte version takes a parameter instead:

```
f=n=>n?[...'{^_}'].join(f(n-1)):'x'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
5Æ="\{^_}"¬qUª'xÃÌ
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NcY9Ilx7Xl99IqxxVaoneMPM&input=)

---

### Explanation

```
5Æ             Ã
```

Generate an array of length 5 and map over it.

```
"\{^_}"¬
```

Split a string to an array of characters

```
qUª'x
```

Rejoin (`q`) to a string using the current value of `U` or (`ª`) `"x"`.

```
=
```

Assign the result of that to `U`.

```
Ì
```

Get the last element in the array.

---

### Alternatives, 18 bytes

Same as above but reducing the array after it's been created.

```
5o r@"\{^_}"¬qX}'x
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NW8gckAiXHteX30irHFYfSd4&input=)

The recursive option.

```
>4©'xª"\{^_}"¬qßUÄ
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=PjSpJ3iqIlx7Xl99Iqxx31XE&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <del>21</del> 20 bytes

```
'x'XJ5:"J'{x^x_x}'Zt
```

-1 byte thanks to *Giuseppe*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X71CPcLL1ErJS726Iq4ivqJWPark/38A)

Comment: 20 bytes with `'x'XJ5:"J'{x^x_x}'Zt` or even `5pc5:"5pc'{x^x_x}'Zt`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
'x5F"{^_}"Ssý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fvcLUTak6Lr5WKbj48N7//wE)

Port of my Python 2 answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
”x“{^_}”j$5¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw9yKRw1zquPia4HMLBXTQwv//wcA)

Port of my Python 2 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>179</s> 167 bytes

@Neil port

```java
interface Y{static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(t.apply(1));}java.util.function.Function<Integer,String>t=N->N>0?Y.t.apply(N-1).replace("x","{x^x_x}"):"x";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xCoMwFEV/RTIloI@61tZuhS4uTlLaEjRKrCYhPiUifnsaaLvdc4dzb88XnmgjVN@8vZcKhW15LaJqm5CjrKNFyyYauVS0RCtVd39wtpXrhGIEPSOYUOKgKAI3Zlhpyli298EKM8oB2lnVKLWC6y@cbmGjEzb@6nI8F0le5IdLBX9FkaQMrDBDOEKJIzHZ3NO93E7YMWC2e/8B)

Comment: I think you it is shorter to write `t` as a real functio  instead of a lambda

Comment: If you use an entire program, `t.apply(1)` should be `t.apply(new Integer(a[0]))` instead. But why not just post a method? [`String t(int n){return n>0?t(n-1).replace("x","{x^x_x}"):"x";}`](https://tinyurl.com/yccencbr) And if the requirement of the challenge would be a full program (which isn't), using a Java 7 recursive method would be shorter than a lambda: `interface Y{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(t(new Integer(a[0])));}static String t(int n){return n>0?t(n-1).replace("x","{x^x_x}"):"x";}}`

Answer (score 0):

## Wolfram Language (*Mathematica*) - 40 characters

Summarizing 3 best answers [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1188472):

#### 40 bytes:

```
Nest["{"<>#<>"_"<>#<>"^"<>#<>"}"&,"x",5]
```

#### 41 bytes:

```
Nest[StringReplace["x"->"{x^x_x}"],"x",5]
```

#### 44 bytes:

```
Last@SubstitutionSystem["x"->"{x^x_x}","x",5]
```

Comment: It is not recommended to answer your own challenge, without leaving others a couple of days first.

Comment: Does your first code snippet not require 41 bytes?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder apologies, the editor form suggested as an option to post my own answer. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I think you should, other users will probably receive this badly.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
jF+\x*5]"{^_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8tNO6ZCyzRWqTouvvb/fwA)

Python 3 translation:

```
from functools import*;print(reduce(lambda x,y:x.join(y),["x"]+5*["{^_}"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
O(o){o--?_(125,O(o,_(95,O(o,_(94,O(o,_(123))))))):_(120);}main(){O(5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99fI1@zOl9X1z5ew9DIVAfI1YnXsIQzTKAMQyNjTQiwAnEMNK1rcxMz8zQ0q/01TIGc////JaflJKYX/9d1ibctKC1JzkgsAgA)